# document.getElementById and document.querySelector won't work twice on the same element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a text-based adventure game and I am using buttons to change the text. I have a start button and when you press it, it changes the text. But I have a yes button, which you the NPC tells you to press, and nothing happens. I have tried to use ctrl-shift-I, and it says there are no errors or warnings. I tried `document.querySelector` instead of `document.getElementById` and I had the same results. I also tried putting it in the data function with no progress.

This is my HTML in the body code

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <p id="text">The D-LABS Space Adventure <br> D-LABS just got more exciting! In this new version, you are lost in space. You need to make the right choices to escape alive and keep you research. Do you have what it takes to win? Press "START" to play.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
  <button class="btn" id="yes" onClick-"yessy()">YES</button>
  <button class="btn" id="start" onClick="data()">START</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my javascript code (I used "#text" instead of "text" when I used querySelector.)

```
function data() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = name+", this is Professer Andromeda. Reply yes if you here this signal. I repeat, "+name+", reply yes if you hear this signal";
}
function yessy() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Okay, good. You are able to hear me "+name+". I am locating you right now...found you! You are in the asteroid belt, right next to the dwarf planet Ceres. Did you know, Ceres was the first object spotted in the asteroid belt? Sorry "+name+". I was just off task. Okay, you can choose to go east, north, or west. Right now, my radar says there is some activity east, but I do not know what it is. I will talk more after you move. Professor Andromeda out.";
}
```

I am new to programming and have searched all over for something to fix this. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Where 'name' is defined?

Comment: And...you have typo here> onClick-"yessy()", should be: onClick="yessy()"

Comment: Thank you very much! I missed that. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

You have got a syntax mistake on the 'Yes' button
Instead of:

```
onClick-"yessy()"
```

change is to

```
onClick="yessy()"
```